# Let user define keyboard shortcut

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard-shortcuts

To ease the use of my JavaFx application I want to allow the user to define a keyboard combination / shortcut to trigger the most important action of the application.

I know how to define a `KeyCodeCombination` in code and set it as `Accelerator` or use it in an KeyEvent listener but instead of hard-coding it, I would like to allow the user to define his own KeyCodeCombination by simply pressing it on his keyboard in a certain settings dialog.

Basically something along this pseudocode:

```
// how would I implement the next two lines
Dialog dialog = new KeyboardShortcutDefinitionDialog();
KeyCombination shortcut = dialog.recordKeyboardShortcut();

// I know how to do the rest from here
shortcutLabel.setText(shortcut.toString());
SettingsManager.storeShortcut(shortcut);
Application.setupShortcut(shortcut);
```

Comment: Listen for a `KeyEvent` and build the `KeyCombination` out of its state. Either that, or do something similar to what Scene Builder does.

Comment: @slaw Listening for the KeyEvent is the part im struggeling with: `KeyTyped` does not give me a proper keycode for `Ctrl + F` or `Ctrl + J` for example. Listening for the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` Events is easy, but then I don't know when to stop listening for new keystrokes: e.g. someone presses `Ctrl + F` and the later on also presses `Shift`. I have no way of determining whether he Meant `Ctrl + F` only or `Ctrl + Shift + F` or even `Shift` only (bad example but I guess you get the gist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small example of listening for a `KEY_PRESSED` event and building a `KeyCombination` out of it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination.Modifier;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var label = new Label();
        label.setFont(Font.font("Segoe UI", 15));
        primaryStage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (!event.getCode().isModifierKey()) {
                label.setText(createCombo(event).getDisplayText());
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(label), 500, 300));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private KeyCombination createCombo(KeyEvent event) {
        var modifiers = new ArrayList<Modifier>();
        if (event.isControlDown()) {
            modifiers.add(KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
        }
        if (event.isMetaDown()) {
            modifiers.add(KeyCombination.META_DOWN);
        }
        if (event.isAltDown()) {
            modifiers.add(KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN);
        }
        if (event.isShiftDown()) {
            modifiers.add(KeyCombination.SHIFT_DOWN);
        }
        return new KeyCodeCombination(event.getCode(), modifiers.toArray(Modifier[]::new));
    }

}
```

Comment: I am little bit worrying, dont will be the app potentially detected by antivirus SW as the keylogger?

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx Hmm, not sure. I suppose it's possible but JavaFX already captures all key events when focused, regardless of whether or not the application code does anything with the event (and that's ignoring things like text input controls).

Comment: This works like a charm. I think my problem was, that I was manually inspecting the properties of the KeyEvent and did not build the KeyCombination right away. This resulted in very odd characters being displayed, when using `Ctrl + J` for example. Thanks for your help!